# ExtJs 3: How to dynamically update grid cell tool tip based on user grid store value?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have tool tip function as bellow

```
function renderTip(val, meta, rec, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
    // meta.tdCls = 'cell-icon'; // icon
    metadata.attr = 'ext:qtip="rec.get('ERROR')"; ext:qclass="maint-usg-data-tip-error"';
    return val;
};
```

i add to tooltip in to grid column as bellow

```
     initComponent: function() {
        colDesc = this.grid.getColumnModel().getColumnById('grid_col_id');
        colDesc.renderer  = this.addToolTip;
     }

Ext.onReady(function() {
 Ext.QuickTips.init(); 
});
```

when update my one row form editable grid that grid store ERROR value update(change). but that not update my tooltip value(`rec.get('ERROR')`). when i reload grid store after grid update(after edit some row cell) that tooltip update for new value.

How can i render update store value to to grid tooltip without reload grid store?

Answer (score 0):

Try using grid.getView().refresh();